# Xamarin re-navigation to mainpage from viewmodel displays empty page

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation

When I re-navigate to my first page (Called Mainpage) from a viewmodel it displays an empty page.

I understand that this is related to the stack but no matter what I try it stays empty. Does anyone has any ideas? I find related threads but not in the same way.

Mainpage constructor:

```
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Code in the viewmodel

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());
```

---

Ok so for extra info:

Setting my rootpage:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());  << Renamed mainpage to login after the suggestion over here 
        MainPage = navigationPage;
    }
```

I call my rootpage after login. I want to make sure my code logs-out my user after the person his/hers ADAL token has expired. It would happen like this in my viewmodel:

```
var auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>();
auth.logout();
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
```

(Without pushAsync is does not navigate at all and stays at the current page. This is called straight after the new page is loaded and the user is logged-in)

Comment: If `MainPage` is your root page `PopToRootAsync` should take you there.

Comment: this is probably unrelated, but save yourself a headache and rename your MainPage class so you can easily tell it apart from XF's MainPage

Comment: Changed the name to login()

Answer (score 0):

In your App.cs you should have defined a `NavigationPage` passing the root of your navigation stack.

Let's say:

```
public class App : Application
{
      public App ()
      {
            NavigationPage navigationPage = new NavigationPage (new MainPage ());
            MainPage = navigationPage;
      }
}
```

The root of your application will be MainPage.

Wherever in your application will call the
 `Navigation.PopToRootAsync();`
 method, you'll go back to your root page. (MainPage in this case)
 
You don't need to push in the stack the MainPage because it's already there, you're popping out all the pages excluding the root.
The constructor of the page won't be called but you can rely on the [Appearing](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Page.Appearing/) event that is fired when the page is displayed.

Comment: Hmm Apparently i already did this. If i only use popToRootAsync is does not navigate to the mainpage.

Comment: Could you post the code where you set your root page? What happen if you use only PopToRootAsync?

Comment: I added the code to the main-post. Hopefully we can make sense of this :)

Comment: and btw Nothin happens when i use only PopToRootAsync

Comment: Could you check if you're pushing the pages on the same NavigationPage from which you're popping out them?

Comment: Yea it is happening like that. It is actually just the second page. Tested it from the view and not the viewmodel and there it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> initialize  static NavigationPage variable in App.cs

```
public class App : Application
{
    public static NavigationPage NavPage;

    public App ()
    {
        NavPage= new NavigationPage (new MainPage ());
        MainPage = NavPage;
    }
}
```

> use NavigationPage variable of App.cs for navigate main page from third page

```
public partial class thirdPage : ContentPage
{
    public thirdPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        main.Clicked += Main_Clicked;
    }

    private void Main_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.NavPage.PopToRootAsync(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @tvt it was worked from viewModel , i can double sure for that